# How to manage tasks in Celery?

Tags: python, celery, task

I have a task with a certain parameter, and I want to know whether there is a task with the same parameter.
I have the following:

```
@task
def some_task(id):
    some_task.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={"id": id})
    some_action_by_id(id)
```

But I would like this:

```
@task
def some_task(id):
    if !check_task(id):
    some_task.update_state(state="PROGRESS", meta={"id": id})
    some_action_by_id(id)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean that you want only one "some_task" running for every unique id at every moment. So you have to implement a locking mechanism. Take a look [here](http://www.loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html). Celery plays great with Redis!

Comment: The author means: t = add.delay(2,4) can not execute twice at the same time. t1 = add.delay(2, 4), the t.id should equ t1.id

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
from celery.result import AsyncResult

def get_same_task(aTaskName, aArgs, aHosts):
    for jobs in aHosts.values():
        for job in jobs:
            if job['name'] == aTaskName and job['args']  == str(aArgs):
                return job['id']
    return None

class IgnoreSameArgumentsTask(Task):
    abstract = True
    inspect = inspect()

    def delay(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        vHosts_Jobs   = self.inspect.active()
        vTaskId = get_same_task(self.name, args, vHosts_Jobs)
        if vTaskId != None:
            return AsyncResult(vTaskId)
        else:
            return super(IgnoreSameArgumentsTask, self).delay(*args,  **kwargs)

@celery.task(base=IgnoreSameArgumentsTask)
def add(x, y):
    sleep(x+y)
    return x + y
```